# Show selected language flag on button in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I simply want to show the flag of the current selected language from the drop down list in the space of button id="flag"

> ex.
>
> If languageCode == eng { the button id="flag" should add class="lang-eng"}
>
> Else if languageCode == th { the button id="flag" should add class="lang-th"}
>
> Else if languageCode == kor { the button id="flag" should add class="lang-kor"}
>
> ....etc.

```
<div class=" navbar-right btn-group center" style="margin-top:8px;">
  <button id="flag" type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
  <button id="arrow" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "cn" })"><span class="lang-cn"></span>  Chinese</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "dutch" })"><span class="lang-dutch"></span>  Dutch</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "en" })"><span class="lang-eng"></span>  English</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "fr" })"><span class="lang-fr"></span>  French</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "ger" })"><span class="lang-ger"></span>  German</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "jap" })"><span class="lang-jap"></span>  Japanese</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "italy" })"><span class="lang-italy"></span>  Italian</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "kor" })"><span class="lang-kor"></span>  Korean</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "mal" })"><span class="lang-mal"></span>  Malaysian</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Language", "Home", new { languageCode = "th" })"><span class="lang-th"></span>  Thai</a>
      </li>                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: not able to understand question??

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla, what is qus?

Comment: @YuliamChandra 

I simply want to show the flag of the current selected language from the drop down list in the space of button id="flag" ex. If languageCode == eng { the button id="flag" should add class="lang-eng"} Else if languageCode == th { the button id="flag" should add class="lang-th"} ....etc.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla 
I simply want to show the flag of the current selected language from the drop down list in the space of button id="flag" example is given above

Comment: where is you drop-down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you redirect the link to /Home/Language, just create a parameter and set it to ViewBag.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Language(string languageCode)
    {
       ViewBag.LanguageCode = languageCode;
       // Redirects to previous page?
       return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
}
```

and change the button html code into

```
<button id="flag" type="button" class="btn btn-default lang-@ViewBag.LanguageCode"></button>
```